# History: Direct Product became Tensor Product?

Tags: vector-spaces, terminology, math-history

A question perhaps for the older members of the stackexchange community .....

I'm reading a 1939 paper by the great and famous J. von Neumann, "On infinite direct products" (of vector spaces), available here http://www.numdam.org/item/?id=CM_1939__6__1_0, legally I presume.

What he calls the *direct product* is clearly what we understand today as a *tensor product*, while our understanding of the *direct product* is the full (possibly infinite) *Cartesian product* with some *projections*.

I'm interested what is the background for this, was this general usage in the dim and distant past, when did the terminology change and why ?

(also posted as https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/12779/history-direct-product-became-tensor-product )

Comment: Wow I had no idea of this change in terminology.
Also, please consider taking your question to [the relevant SE site](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/).
First time ever I look at a paper of Von Noumann. Nice writing.

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz. Posted as you suggested.